# Updating instance attributes of class

Tags: python

I have been googling a lot on this topic and I did not really find a commonly accepted way of achieving my goal.

Suppose we have the following class:

```
import numpy as np
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        self.length = x.size

    def append(self, data):
        self.x = np.append(self.x, data)
```

and `x` should be a numpy array! If I run

```
A = MyClass(x=np.arange(10))
print(A.x)
print(A.length)
```

I get

`[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]` and `10`. So far so good. But if I use the append method

```
A.append(np.arange(5))
```

I get `[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4]` and `10`. This is also expected since the instance attribute `length` was set during the instantiation of `A`. Now I am not sure what the most pythonic way of updating instance attributes is. For example I could run `__init__` again:

```
A.__init__(A.x)
```

and then the `length` attribute will have the correct value, but in some other posts here I found that this is somehow frowned upon. Another solution would be to update the `length` attribute in the `append` method directly, but I kind of want to avoid this since I don't want to forget updating an attribute at some point. Is there a more pythonic way of updating the `length` attribute for this class?

Comment: Why don't you make `length` a `@property` of class `MyClass`? You may find documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't *update* it, just *read* it when you need it with [a getter](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#property):

```
class MyClass:
    ...

    @property
    def length(self):
        return self.x.size
```

Comment: Ah, yes. That certainly is another possibility and would indeed work well in this case.  Thanks!